# Multiple conditions in a for loop

Tags: coffeescript

I am having a question regarding coffeescript for loop.

Single condition case is achieved by:

```
-> foo for foo in foos when foo is bar
```

and it produces:

```
(function() {
  var foo, _i, _len, _results;
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = foos.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    foo = foos[_i];
    if (foo === bar) _results.push(foo);
  }
  return _results;
});
```

which is perfect.

However, I have a case where there are multiple conditions involved and the construct above does not support them as far as I know. This one:

```
->
  for foo in foos
    if foo is bar
      foo
    else if foo isnt bar
      bar
```

does and it compiles into:

```
(function() {
  var foo, _i, _len, _results;
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = foos.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    foo = foos[_i];
    if (foo === bar) {
      _results.push(foo);
    } else if (foo !== bar) {
      _results.push(bar);
    } else {
      _results.push(void 0);
    }
  }
  return _results;
});
```

which is ok, but I was wondering if there is a way to get rid of extra `else` statement. Right now I added:

```
else
  return undefined
```

which prevents pushing to `_results` and it works.

So, is there a construct in coffeescript similar to the first example but for multiple conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if...else` solution looks perfectly fine to me. Remember that `when` is for actually skipping values. For instance,

```
num for num in [1, 2, 3, 4] when num % 2 is 0
```

will give you

```
[2, 4]
```

By contrast, if you want the loop to return a list with the same length as the input, you should be using a conditional inside—either `if...else` or `switch`.

Comment: I went with if...else solution and manual refactoring of javascript afterwards since there seems to be no construct in coffeescript which satisfies what I was looking for (a way not to return value to variable which is a problem specially in loop within a loop).

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you can play with it like this:

```
-> select foo for foo in foos when foo matches bar
```

It will require a function to handle `select` and `matches` but it would give you the syntax you are looking for:

```
(function() {
  var foo, _i, _len, _results;
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = foos.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    foo = foos[_i];
    if (foo(matches(bar))) _results.push(select(foo));
  }
  return _results;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your snippets I would just use:

```
foo for foo in foos when foo is bar or foo isnt bar
```

but they're perhaps oversimplificated